# Histogram with big value and a lot of small value

Tags: tikz-pgf, histogram

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 symbolic x coords={100,95,90,85,81,80},
 ylabel = {x},
 xlabel = {y},
 bar width=0.20cm,
 height=7cm,
 width=15cm,
 xtick=data]
 \addplot[ybar,fill=black] coordinates {
    (80,356)
    (81,63)
    (85,9.9)
    (90,0.9)
    (95,0.4)
    (100,0.5)
 };
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like the change the scale of my histogram given that I have a lot small values than big ones. Is there a way to scale the y axis? I want to make the small value appear a little more so that I can see the difference between my 60 and 10 let's say. Right now I can't because of the 356 make small values almost invisible.

Comment: Can you show them as log values?  Would that make sense for your data?

Comment: It would not make sense in log.